# In a Numba compiled code, how to access a numba.types.Record particular field without hardcoding the field name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I have a situation where I must access a field of an structured array by the index, instead of by the name. For e.g:

```
array[1]  # of course in reality this number is dynamic
```

Where the dtype of the array is:

```
Record(Date[type=int64;offset=0],Tag[type=int64;offset=8],Key[type=int64;offset=16])
```

But If I attempt to do this, it fails with:

```
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (Record(Date[type=int64;offset=0],Tag[type=int64;offset=8],Key[type=int64;offset=16]), int64)
```

Essentially telling me that there is no version of getitem that takes an int.

If I attempt to access by the column name, it works:

```
array['Date']  # <== This is just fine
```

So I tried creating a simple function that converts the index to the column name (had to return an array of ascii codes because Numba doesn't support strings, it seems):

```
@njit([types.Array(types.uint8, 1, 'C', readonly=True)(types.int16)], nogil=True)
def get_column_name_for_index(idx):
    if idx == 0:
        return np.frombuffer(b'Date', dtype=np.uint8)
    if idx == 1:
        return np.frombuffer(b'Tag', dtype=np.uint8)

    return np.frombuffer(b'Key', dtype=np.uint8)
```

So I could try to:

```
array[get_column_name_for_index(1)]
```

But this fails because I can't use a `uint8` array there either.

I thought that If I could transform that `unit8` array into a string and use that string to access the column by name. I found a way, but still when it gets to that point it fails with:

Invalid use of Function() with argument(s) of type(s): (Record(Date[type=int64;offset=0],Tag[type=int64;offset=8],Key[type=int64;offset=16]), unicode_type)

How can I access a particular field (that will be decided at runtime) from a `numba.types.Record` by index or by name, or by any other means?

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to `numba` you can index fields by number using the `dtype.names` attribute:

```
In [139]: A = np.zeros(3, 'U3,i,f')                                                                  
In [140]: A                                                                                          
Out[140]: 
array([('', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.), ('', 0, 0.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U3'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
In [141]: A['f1']                                                                                    
Out[141]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [142]: A.dtype.names                                                                              
Out[142]: ('f0', 'f1', 'f2')
In [143]: A[A.dtype.names[1]]                                                                        
Out[143]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried but the `names` attribute is stripped out when Numba compiles, so that is not available.